# Low pass filter processing image java

Tags: java, image-processing, filter, fft

how to implements low pass filter, i have:

```
BufferedImage img;
int width = img.getWidth();
int height = img.getHeight();

int L = (int) (f * Math.min(width, height));

for (int y = 0 ; y < height ; y++) {
    for (int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++) {
        if (x >= width / 2 - L && x <= width / 2 + L && y >= -L + height / 2 && y <= L + height / 2) {
            img.setRGB(x, y, 0);
        }
        else {}
    }
}
```

but firstly i should transform image but how?

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written would just set the pixels near the edge of the image to black. If you did this in the frequency domain you would have a low-pass filter, because the pixels near the edge of the image would be the high-frequency components and so setting them to 0 would leave just the low-frequency components. To operate in the frequency domain you need to apply a Fourier transform. However you need to take care about where in the transformed image the low-frequency components end up, as different implementations of a Fourier transform may put the low-frequency components either in the center of the transformed image or at one of the corners.